# A question of chance.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I'm having a bit of trouble with this problem.

Three cards are drawn from a pack of regular playing cards. What's the probability of getting different suits, as well as different denominations (number, face, etc.)?

Bonus question. In the above case, it isn't specified whether the cards are drawn simultaneously, or one by one. Would it make a difference?

Comment: let's say you get ace hearts on 1, you then have to get any card 2 - king which is a spade, diamond, club - so you have 3 x 12 = 36 that are ok, out of 51 cards remaining in deck.  Then on third draw you have 2 suits and 11 denominations from the 50 remaining (22 / 50)

Comment: Would there be a difference, if we drew them all simultaneously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first one is 'any card' P = 1

2nd drawing has to be 12 denominations out of 3 suits, so it is 36 out of 51 remaining p2 = 36 / 51

3rd drawing 11 denominations from 2 suits, 22 / 50

answer = (36 / 51) (22 / 50) = 132 / 425

---

bonus question - drawing method makes no difference, unless there is replacement and a reshuffle after each card, which changes things, it would make the denominator go back to 52 in each fraction, since you could redraw the same card - but I don't think they mean that - with my method you could take 3 straight off the top and check them, or deal them one-by-one, it makes no difference

Comment: Your answer does check out with the one I was given, so, you must be right.